# JAXB : Order of elements in multiple lists

Tags: java, jaxb, xml-binding

I have two lists in my root element object. 
`List<Person>` persons and `List<Address>` addresses . When i marshall this , it prints first all the person and then all the addresses . I want to print it one by one . Person then address , person and address and so on . How can i do that in JAXB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`@XmlElements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElements.html) or [`@XmlElementRefs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementRefs.html).

Assuming neither `Person` extends `Address` nor vice versa, the code will be something like:

```
@XmlElements {
    @XmlElement(name="Person", type=Person.class),
    @XmlElement(name="Address", type=Address.class)
}
private List<Object> personOrAddress;
```

However consider remodelling it as a special type like `PointOfContact` so that you don't have a heterogeneous property.